# Building an AMI using Packer with Python & Python modules (using pip) installed via powershell script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ami, packer

Using Packer, I am trying to create a Windows AMI with Python + the cryptography module installed. Here is the installation command I'm using for Python:

```
Invoke-Expression "python-3.6.8-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0"
```

Standalone that works fine. If I launch an EC2 instance from the resulting AMI, I can open Powershell and execute `python --version` and it returns the Python version. This is to be expected since, according to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui), `PrependPath=1` will "Add install and Scripts directories to PATH"
In addition, however, I want to install cryptography module so I add the following to the install script:

```
Invoke-Expression "python-3.6.8-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0"
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install cryptography
```

Now Packer will fail when it gets to the pip command saying `The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a amazon-ebs.windows: cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`
I tried adding pip's location to the system path in multiple different ways but nothing helped. What *did* work (as well as the addition to the system path) was adding a sleep after the Python install command. Seemingly Packer/Powershell doesn't wait for the Python installer to finish. So now my install script looks like this:

```
Invoke-Expression "python-3.6.8-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0"
sleep 30
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\"
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install cryptography
```

Now Packer executes no problem and creates the new AMI but when I launch the resulting AMI and run `python --version` I get `'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` Adding commands to the script to append the system path has not helped.

Can anyone shed any light on this predicament?

Comment: PS uses for the path the environmental variable PSMODULEPATH which can be modified by pressing start button and typing Edit Environmental Variable.  Also see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367816/python-error-when-run-qgis-couldnt-load-sip-module?force_isolation=true

Comment: As an aside, on a general note: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); except in unusual circumstances, [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script / command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Comment: @jdweng, `PSMODULEPATH` has nothing to do with this question, and neither is the link helpful. What matters with respect to execution of _external programs_ is the `Path` environment variable, which Jay already knows how to modify in-process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside:

- [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); except in unusual circumstances, [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script / command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).
- The commands below use *direct* invocation of `./python-3.6.8-amd64.exe` with individual arguments - no need to call via a command line stored in a *string*.

---

There are two problems with your code:

- Your `./python-3.6.8-amd64.exe` installer appears to be *GUI*-subsystem application, which therefore runs *asynchronously* by default.

  - Your `sleep 30` approach to await completion of the installer *isn't reliable*, as there's no guarantee that it will complete in that time frame, given that execution time may vary based on external factors (system load). Below are two reliable alternatives.
  - A simple trick for making such a call *synchronous* - i.e. to *wait for its completion* - is to append an additional pipeline segment (what specific command you use in that last segment is irrelevant; here, `Out-Host` is used, which would print any stdout output (which GUI applications rarely produce) to the console; use `Out-Null` to suppress any such output); this approach has the additional advantage that the *exit code* of the process is reflected in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131324/45375) for background information):

    ```
    # Note the ... | Out-Host at the end.
    python-3.6.8-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0 | Out-Host
    # Inspect $LASTEXITCODE to see if the installer signaled
    # failure via a nonzero value.
    ```
  - Alternatively, use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with the `-Wait` parameter:

    ```
    Start-Process -Wait python-3.6.8-amd64.exe '/quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0'
    ```

    - To obtain the process exit code in this case, use the `-PassThru` switch and examine the `.ExitCode` property value of the process-info object that `-PassThru` emits:

      ```
      $exitCode = (Start-Process -PassThru -Wait python-3.6.8-amd64.exe '/quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0').ExitCode
      ```
- Whatever modifications the installer makes to the *persistent*, registry-based `Path` environment variable (`$env:Path`) are *not* immediately seen in the *same session* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71415530/45375) for background information).

  - You can use the following command to explicitly refresh your session's `Path` value - this should make the `pip` Python executable discoverable:

    ```
    $env:PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine'),
                [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') -join ';'
    ```
  - However, there may be a better, Packer-specific approach, mentioned in a since-deleted answer by [Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3390419/paolo): use of a *separate shell provisioner* in which the modified `Path` value is *automatically* seen (I don't know Packer, so I cannot spell out this solution.)

Comment: I'm glad to hear the answer helped, and I appreciate the nice feedback as well as the coffee, @Jay. I've just updated the answer, which should address all your points.